# The behavior of Task seems to differ in Playground environments

Tags: swift, concurrency, task, swift-playground

In an actual app project, when running the following code, the print statements occur in the order of 1->3->2:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Text
    .onAppear {
        print("1")
        Task {
            print("2")
        }
        print("3")
    }
}
```

However, when executing the equivalent code in Playground, the print statements occur in the order of 1->2->3:

```swift
print("1")
Task {
    print("2")
}
print("3")
```

After conducting several tests in the Playground environment, I observed that running the function inside Task on the mainActor or lowering the priority of the Task significantly (e.g., .background) results in order of 1->3->2:

```swift
print("1")
Task { @MainActor in
    print("2")
}
print("3")

// or
print("1")
Task(priority: .background) {
    print("2")
}
print("3")
```

However, without these additional configuration, I believe that the print order in Playground also should be 1->3->2.

Could you please explain why in Playground the execution order is 1->2->3?

Comment: Why should there be any particular order to the print statements?

Comment: There's no special reason. I'm just curious about why it's behaving so differently when I look at the print results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Old version**

> It's because in app project your code really starts with something like this:
>
>    @main // Magic here!
>    struct ExampleSwiftUIApp: App {

**Updated**

As [@Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob) points out for an actual app project:

> The main actor isolation stems more directly from the body of the View

**Standing point**

So `Task` in app project runs [on behalf of the current actor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5ltye) (which is **main** here). So code executes [like on main queue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor). Main queue is **serial** so order 1->3->2 is guaranteed in app example.

Now let's look at in-Playground-example. Here you are creating task without actor. Task without actor runs simultaneously with base flow of code. In your sample base flow is `print("3")`. And, yes, `print("3")` runs on main thread. But. There is no main actor and so I believe that in Playground

```swift
Task {
    print("2")
}
```

produces [detached task](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency/#Tasks-and-Task-Groups:%7E:text=specifically%20as%20a-,detached%20task,-%2C%20call%20the%20Task). So order of execution `2` vs `3` is not guaranteed and may depends on priorities, number of free CPU cores, etc.

Comment: The main actor isolation stems more directly from the [`body`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/body-8kl5o) of the `View`. That’s the operative isolation, not of the `App` itself. But your point stands.